# Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined in Google Oauth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I'm use `Oauth` for developing for chrome extension and user can login by Google Account.I have code jquery as below.

I'm also include js library in html file:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/client.js"></script>
```

and have JS function:

```
function handleAuthClick(event) {
gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: clientID,
    scope: scopes,
    response_type: 'code token id_token gsession',
    access_type: accessType,
    immediate: false
}, handleAuthResult);
return false;
}
```

My **problem** is: I can not login by google account and it show error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined`.

**Note**: If I'm run as html I can login normally, but I can not sign in when use as chrome extension.

Comment: check the value of gapi and gapi.auth

Comment: Are there any network errors loading JS files?

Comment: where are you including these scripts and running that code

Comment: Could you please put the code in a fiddle for us? Maybe your function is above the script calls. As a function declaration will be always available, when executed, if the gapi variable was not initialized will become a Global implied with undefined as its value.

Try to log into the console the gapi value, if it´s an object, then you may have a problem with the order that you´re using to place your function and script calls.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that gapi.auth is still not initialised and the reason for that is that you didn't follow the proper chain of steps to set it up before making this call.
So I am just putting here a sample for you to see if you are missing any of the steps while initializing the gapi object successfully. Here it goes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function( gapi ) {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey); // your variable for apiKey
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);

        function checkAuth() {
            gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientID, scope: scopes, immediate: true},   handleAuthResult);
        }

        function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
            var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('id-of-your-login-button');
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                makeApiCall();
            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
                authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
            }
        }

      function handleAuthClick(event) {
          gapi.auth.authorize({
              client_id: clientID,
              scope: scopes,
              response_type: 'code token id_token gsession',
              access_type: accessType,
              immediate: false
          }, handleAuthResult);
          return false;
       }
     })( gapi );
</script>
```

You can safely put this script tag in your body tag just below the button html code.